# Finding glass needed for a light bulb using surface area?

Tags: calculus

If I found the surface area of a light bulb, and have been told to use that to find the amount of glass needed to make the bulb, assuming the glass is 0.015 inches thick, what would I do to find how much glass needed?

Comment: The volume of glass would be approximately the thickness times the surface area, with this approximation improving as the surface becomes thinner.

Comment: @Ian so my answer would just be SA * 0.015?

Comment: Sure (but pay attention to units).

Comment: @Ian is there anyway I can get an exact

Comment: @Ian exact answer, or is this approximation the best hah can be done?

Comment: To get an exact answer you would need to have some idea of the area of the "intermediate surfaces". If they are all the same (for example, if your shape is a cylinder, and the "surfaces" are circles) then this is exact. If not then it is an approximation of the true answer which is expressed in terms of an integral. An example where this would come up is with a sphere: a spherical shell has true volume $\frac{4\pi}{3} (R^3-r^3)$ where $R$ is the outer radius and $r$ is the inner radius, which is approximately $4\pi r^2(R-r)$ if $R-r$ is small.

Answer (score 0):

If the bulb is a sphere

$$ V = 4 \pi(r_2^3-r_1^3)/3 $$

if $r$ is average of the two radii, thickness $t= r_2 -r_1,$ and

$$ r_1 >> t, \quad r_2 >> t , \, V \approx 4 \pi r^2 \, t $$

So approximately also $ V = t \cdot Area $.

Comment: What's $t$? ${}{}$

Comment: thickness of glass bulb